# vim: create file with +x bit

Tags: shell-script, vim, executable, chmod

Is there any way to set `+x` bit on script while creating?

For example I run:

```
vim -some_option_to_make_file_executable script.sh
```

and after saving I can run file without any additional movings.

ps. I can run `chmod` from `vim` or even from console itself, but this is a little annoying, cause `vim` suggests to reload file. Also it's annoying to type `chmod` command every time.
pps. It would be great to make it depending on file extension (I don't need executable `.txt` :-) )

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I don't recall where I found this, but I use the following in my ~/.vimrc

```
" Set scripts to be executable from the shell
au BufWritePost * if getline(1) =~ "^#!" | if getline(1) =~ "/bin/" | silent !chmod +x <afile> | endif | endif
```

The command automatically sets the executable bit if the first line starts with "#!" or contains "/bin/".

Comment: Wow, that's great thing. Btw, seems you can join two `if`'s into one `if getline(1) =~ "^#!/bin/"`. Anyway that's amazing. Thank you.

Comment: This is not a "or". I prefer to use just first condition, `au BufWritePost * if getline(1) =~ "^#!" | silent !chmod +x % | endif`

Comment: @rush The reasons for the double if statements is to to catch lines where the the `/bin` doesn't immediately follow the shebang, like `#!/usr/bin/env`. A way around that is of course to use a wildcard: `getline(1) =~ "^#!.*/bin/"`.

Comment: Neat trick but I get the following every time I save: `written/bin/bash: endif: command not found
/bin/bash: endif: command not found`

Comment: this fixes it: `au BufWritePost * if getline(1) =~ "^#!" | if getline(1) =~ "/bin/" | silent execute "!chmod a+x <afile>" | endif | endif`

Answer (score 4):

I found [this script](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Setting_file_attributes_without_reloading_a_buffer) at http://vim.wikia.com. Not a perfect solution, but a acceptable one, I think.

```
function! SetExecutableBit()
  let fname = expand("%:p")
  checktime
  execute "au FileChangedShell " . fname . " :echo"
  silent !chmod a+x %
  checktime
  execute "au! FileChangedShell " . fname
endfunction
command! Xbit call SetExecutableBit()
```

You can now set the execute bit with the command `:Xbit`.
All credit to Max Ischenko at vim.wikia.com

Answer (score 1):

I wrote myself a version of this that is a bit more selective. It only makes the file executable when writing a new file, and only if it starts with `#!`. This version also avoids executing an external command, doing everything in pure vimscript.

```
" automatically make script files executable when writing for the first time
function! NewScriptExec() abort
    " check if this is a new file which starts with a shebang
    if exists('s:new_file') && getline(1)[0:1] == '#!'
        " based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/57539332/370695
        let l:file = expand('%')
        let l:old_perm = getfperm(l:file)
        " set the exec bit everywhere the read bit is set
        let l:new_perm = substitute(l:old_perm, '\v(r.)-', '\1x', 'g')
        if (l:old_perm != l:new_perm)
            call setfperm(l:file, l:new_perm)
        endif
        unlet s:new_file
    endif
endfunction

augroup new_script_exec
        autocmd!
        autocmd BufNewFile * let s:new_file = 1
        autocmd BufWritePost * call NewScriptExec()
augroup END
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this in MacVim Custom Version 8.0.648 (134)

```
" if file is executable just exit

au BufWritePost *.sh if FileExecutable("%") | if getline(1) =~ "^#!" | silent !chmod u+x % | endif | endif

" Determines if file is already executable 

function! FileExecutable(fname)

    execute "silent! ! test -x" a:fname
    return v:shell_error

endfunction
```

Answer (score 0):

tonymac's answer stopped working for me at some point (with VIM 7.4), giving me the same problem as @StevieD. Modifying it fixed the problem:

```
au BufWritePost * if getline(1) =~ "^#!" | if getline(1) =~ "/bin/" | silent execute "!chmod +x <afile>" | endif | endif
```

I found the answer from https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=126304, although @StevieD also gave the same answer.